# Find data from third column based on two other columns

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have three columns: A, B and C. One has `name`, second has `father name` and  third has `ID` numbers. I want to find the ID number using `name` and `father name` because `name` column has same name entries.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest filtering. With labels in Row1 and in say D1:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(2,C:C)>1,"Duplicates!",SUBTOTAL(9,C:C))
```

you should have no need for further keying (just click on your selections) but (a) still have access to the result in a fixed location (ie D1) while also (b) getting a warning should say two people have the same Name and Father name or the one person have more than a single ID.

For future use it may be worth you creating an extra column with Name and Father name concatenated, as suggested by @John, and perhaps also copying your ID column into a new column on the left, to make VLOOKUP based on ID easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate columns A and B and then use `VLOOKUP` on the combined key (which is more likely to be unique and what you want).

If you have MS Access (because you've bought MS Office) I'd recommend doing this kind of thing in Access.  It's more suited for what you want to do (as well as other tasks like it):

```
Select id_number from your_table where name="theName" and fathername="theFatherName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the combination of Index & Match formula.

Formula = `=INDEX($C$1:$C$5,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$5=F2)*($B$1:$B$5=F3),0))` 
As its array formula press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd> after entering the formula.

[image]

Comment: thanks this is working but only when i copy the data from the columns but when i will enter the data by keyboard it does not work

Comment: @user2934643  You need to adjust the rows accordingly. Like in the demo there are 5 rows so range is `C1:C5`. If you have 500 rows then formula will look like `INDEX($C$1:$C$500,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$500=F2)*($B$1:$B$500=F3),0))`